# How to know when a query was executed?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

1. How to find out when a query was executed? I ran a query couple of days ago, I'm not sure about the exact time. I want to know at what date and time the query was executed.
   Is it possible to get that information?
2. How to check the server status when a query is running? What information should be checked?

version -oracle 11g

Comment: if you know the sql_id of sql AND server is not bounced, then you can check in v$sqlstats (last_active_time might be useful). for server status, if you have OEM, use it, else you can resort to scripts. What to monitor depends on what do you want to monitor.

Comment: Are you licensed to use the AWR?  Is it reasonable to expect that the query that was executed was one of the top resource consumers in the window during which it was executed?  How long (roughly) did the query take to run?

Answer (score 1):

```
select LAST_LOAD_TIME, LAST_ACTIVE_TIME 
from v$sql
where sql_id = Your SQL ID
```

Hope this will give you the expected result

Comment: If a query was last executed a couple of days ago, it's pretty unlikely that it is going to still be present in `v$sql`.  Not impossible, but I certainly wouldn't bet on it.